# Objective-C to Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift

How can I do this in Swift?

```
-  (void)handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)sender { 
    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
      NSLog(@"UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded");
    //Do Whatever You want on End of Gesture
     }
    else if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan){
       NSLog(@"UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan.");
   //Do Whatever You want on Began of Gesture
     }
  }
```

I don't know how to transform that sender declaration in Swift. Thanks!

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code translation service. I would suggest that you take some time and learn both languages (Objective-C and Swift)

Comment: Yes, I know, but I am new in XCode and I try to do my best but sometimes I can't figure it out ... Sorry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's essentially the same code -- a function that checks the value of the parameter's `state` property:

```
func handleLongPress(gestureRecognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    switch gestureRecognizer.state {
    case .Began:
        println("UIGestureRecognizerState.Began")
    case .Ended:
        println("UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended")
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Minor remark: Wouldn't a switch statement be more swifty?

Comment: @MartinR Sure, why not?

Comment: I added this to my code but my app crashes when I tap and hold the screen.
In didMoveToView I have this:

let holdGesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleLongPress")
        view.addGestureRecognizer(holdGesture)

Comment: @user2012374 You're using the wrong selector. You've specified one that takes no arguments, which is not the case here.

Comment: And what should I use instead?

Comment: let holdGesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleLongPress:")

Answer (score -3):

```
func handleLongPress (sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer){

  if sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded {
     println(UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
  }else if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan){
    println(UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
  }
}
```

try this. I just translated what you have written in obj-c

Comment: I added this to my code but my app crashes when I tap and hold the screen. In didMoveToView I have this: let holdGesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleLongPress") view.addGestureRecognizer(holdGesture)